# (BigQuery) Left join to gather lowest data from Left table that is greater than data from right table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis

I need to LEFT JOIN a table with only the lowest values in the right table that are greater than other values in the left table.

I can do this with ROW_NUMBER and Subqueries but the issue is that I need to do the same with about 5 Actions from 5 different tables and I dont want a 10-page long query that is difficult for my coworkers to audit.

I have Table.Users that measures when a user does an action. I want to left join it with Table.Action1 to gather the first incident of action1 that occurs after the action in Table.Users.

Users can appear multiple times in both tables.

Is there any way to gather only one row each from multiple LEFT JOINs without multiple subqueries?

I cant use aggregations as there is a lot of info I need from the action tables that is connected to the specific actions.

My data would look like:
Table.Users:

```
| User_id | Date |
| 1       | 1    |
| 1       | 2    |
| 1       | 3    |
| 1       | 4    |
| 1       | 5    |
| 1       | 6    |
```

Table.Action1

```
| User_id | Date |Action.id|
| 1       | 1    |1|
| 1       | 2    |2|
| 1       | 5    |3|
| 1       | 6    |4|
```

Ideal Result:
Table.Users:

```
| User_id | Date |Action1.Date| Action1.id
| 1       | 1    |2           |2|
| 1       | 2    |5           |3|
| 1       | 3    |5           |3|
| 1       | 4    |5           |3|
| 1       | 5    |6           |4|
| 1       | 6    |            | |
```

I have solved this before with multiple subqueries and ROW_NUMBER but I have many more tables that need joining now and dont want a very long query that is difficult for a co-worker to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no duplicate `(user_id, dt)` in the `actions` table, as shown in your sample data, one option uses a `left join` to bring the matching action (if any), and then window function `last_value()` with option `ignore nulls` to retrieve the relevant action date and id. The trick is to carefully adjust the window clause:

```
select u.*, 
    last_value(a.dt ignore nulls) over w last_action_dt,
    last_value(a.id ignore nulls) over w last_action_id
from users u
left join actions a on a.user_id = u.user_id and a.dt = u.dt
window w as (
    partition by u.user_id 
    order by u.dt desc
    rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
)
order by u.user_id, u.dt
```

Side note: I renamed column `date` to `dt` in the query, so it does not clash with the corresponding SQL keyword.

Comment: What does the "window w as..." do that that "OVER ( PARTITION BY u.user_id ORDER BY a.dt DESC)" after the LAST_VALUE  couldnt?  I havent used that function before as part of a join.

Comment: @Lewp: nothing; it is just a syntactical sugar in BQ, so that we don't need to type the whole `OVER` clause twice (once for each `last_value()`).

Comment: So, If I use LAST_VALUE to to gather all values I need from all joined tables I can then select all distinct rows to get result that has been de-duped assuming the first table has no duplicates?

Comment: @Lewp:  my query addresses the sample data that you have showed. I can't really answer your additional question without seeing all the *joined tables* that you mention. You may want to try and adapt the query for your actual tables, and come back with [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: To update, I used these functions to grab  the data I needed on all LEFT JOINS that would created duplicate rows the selected all distinct rows from that Query before doing my aggregating, additional analyses.  Each duplicate creating table needed its own WINDOW defined and along with Greater than or equal to parameters in the JOIN  ON Clause.  Thanks for the Help!